# Trouble writing SQL Query using COUNT

Tags: sql, count

[image]

I am trying to write an SQL Query where I print the name, gender from table 1 along with the number of participants. The id tags in Table 1 and Table 2 are the same, so my idea is to group the participants via id tags and then count them.

```
$sql = 'SELECT T1.name, T1.gender, COUNT(T2.Participant_name) AS participant_count
                FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
                WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id
                GROUP T2.Id';
```

The logic makes sense to me, however, nothing seems to be printing and I’m unsure where I have gone wrong.

Desired Output:

- Name,gender,number of participants
- A,M,2
- B,M,1
- C,F,1

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: and the actual output of the given query :) And the RDBMS you're using

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Thuhin I included the desired output and I'm trying to execute the query through PHP

Comment: @Alexey Added the expected output and I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Try below group by with two columns T1.name, T1.gender

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.gender, COUNT(T2.Participant_name) AS participant_count
                FROM Table1 T1 inner join Table2 T2 
                on T1.Id = T2.Id
                GROUP T1.name, T1.gender
```

OR you can try this

```
select T1.name, T1.gender, T1.age,participant_count from
Table1 T1 inner join
( SELECT ID,COUNT(Participant_name) AS participant_count
                    FROM Table2  
                    GROUP ID
)T2 on T1.Id = T2.Id
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand why I have to group name/gender. I'm trying to count number of participants for each ID, hence I am grouping the participants with similar ID

Comment: @JasonMetr number of column in selection and group by need to be same which is maximum dbms rule

Comment: @fa06 For simplicity sake for the question, I eliminated 1 column from Table 1. So I basically added the additional column to both SELECT and group. The query doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JasonMetr, could you please elaborate your question

Comment: @fa06 The expected output is in my main question. For the purpose of the question, My table 1 prints 2 existing columns along with the newly computed column. However, in my actual code, I am printing 3 separate columns along with the new column. Hence, I tried using your code by adding the new column to Select and Group which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is that coulmn value @JasonMetr

Comment: SELECT T1.name, T1.gender, T1.age ....... .... GROUP T1.name,T1.gender,T1.age // I added T1. age to both the Select and the Group segment and the query isn't working

Comment: @JasonMetr, I've update the answer and provide 2nd solution- you can try that

Answer (score 0):

You should change the group statement, cause when you group by the column that you count, result would be always 1

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.gender, COUNT(T2.Participant_name) AS participant_count
                FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
                WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id
                GROUP BY T1.name, T1.gender
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of grouping T1. name and T1.gender. I am trying to count number of participants for each ID / For example Id 1 has 2 participants, Id 2 has 1 participant, Id 3 has 1 participant

Comment: If you need to select name and gender, you need to put them on grouping otherwise you will get an query syntax error. For each ID you you have 1 name and gender assigned, grouping by ID or name and gender will give you the same result at the end

Comment: For simplicity sake for the question, I eliminated 1 column from Table 1. So I basically added the additional column to both SELECT and group. The query doesn't seem to work